# If $A$ is symmetric matrix and $P$ is matrix of orthogonal projection,what is then matrix $P\cdot A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be symmetric matrix, and $P$ be matrix of orthogonal projection on null space of matrix $A$. What can you say about matrix $P\cdot A$ ?
$$ $$
The fact is that symmetric matrices have $n$ different eigenvalues, and $n$ different independent eigenvectors. That means that rank of symmetric matrix is full. Because of that, null space of symmetric matrix will be only zero-vector.I can conclude then that P can't be calculate on null space. Am I right?
$$ $$But if my P was matrix of orthogonal projection on column space of symmetric matrix $A$, I would say that P is identity matrix $(P=A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T})$. So,matrix $PA$ will be only matrix $A$.
If someone wanted to find orthogonal projection of some vector on fundamental subspaces, that vector will be in column space of matrix $A$, because $v_p=Pv$ gives exactly that given vector, and null space of $A^{T}$ will be $v_p=(I-P)v=0$. I would like if someone correct me if I do something wrong..

Comment: The $0$ matrix is symmetric and not of full rank.

Comment: Yes,you're right. But in generally, what can I say about matrix $PA$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that the symmetric matrices have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, but not $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Note that diagonal matrix is a special form of symmetric matrix. To each $i$-th diagonal entry, we can assign value $\lambda_i$ to make any set of reals $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n\}$, counted with multiplicity, as a set of eigenvalues of $A$. Accordingly, $\ker A$ (the $0$ eigenspace) does not have to be trivial.

The answer to your problem is quite simple: $PA = O$ whenever $P$ is an orthogonal projection onto $\ker A$. To see this, note that for all $y=Ax \in \mathcal R (A)$ (the range of $A$) and $z\in \ker A$, it holds that
$$
\langle y,z\rangle =\langle Ax,z\rangle = \langle x,A^T z\rangle = \langle x,A z\rangle=\langle x, 0\rangle=0.
$$ This shows $\mathcal R(A)\perp \ker A$, which implies that $Py=PAx=0$ for all $x$. Thus $PA=O$.